# How to send an email from yahoo email by using php curl

Tags: php

You know facebook has an API. so, my site's users can login with their facebook accounts on my website.

Does yahoo have an API like facebook? Did anyone see a yahoo API? Ive been looking for a yahoo API for 5 hours, i cannot find it. I wanted to ask this question here , because there are so many php coders here, and someone maybe tried it before.

Id like my site's users to login to their yahoo account and send mail from their account. I wanna use php curl function, or anything elses..

I found this code block:

> http://codeglobe.blogspot.com/2009/07/login-and-get-contacts-yahoo-mail-with.html

However i was not able to connect my yahoo account and send an email..

Well, please inform me if you have some informations on this issue..
regards

Comment: I doubt their API will allow you to send messages. Perhaps using SMTP is what you want to do? In which case, you should look up their help docs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [yahoo's mail api](http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/).